# Fazer com que um elemento DIV fique posicionada como rodapé

Tags: javascript, css, div, posicionamento, footer

Este é um exemplo do que estou tentando ajustar:

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
html,body {
   height: 100%;
}
#topo {
   background: limegreen;
   position: static;
   left: 60px;
   top: 35px;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 200px;
}
#conteudo {
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   position: absolute;
   left: 15%;
   top: 15%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 70%;
   height: auto;
}
#rodape {
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   background: limegreen;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="topo">
   <h1>Titulo</h1>
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div id="rodape">RODAPE</div>
```

Note que estou tentando permanecer a `div` denominada como *rodapé*, abaixo da `div` chamada *conteúdo*.

A tarefa pode ser feita utilizando tanto CSS quanto Javascript, desde de que não altere drasticamente o *layout* aqui disposto no exemplo. Pois o design reflete o projeto real, e alterá-lo de forma inesperada ocasionará em um *re-design*.

Então desejo saber o que pode-se feito. Vale ressaltar que a regra `fixed` não é bem vinda para o caso.

Comment: Mas vc quer que o rodapé fique exatamente embaixo do conteúdo ou fixo na parte inferior da tela?

Comment: Cara uma maneira de resolver isto seria com *Flexbox*, pra vc seria ruim usá-lo? Melhor do que usar float.

Comment: Seria o que o @hugocsl postou como resposta utilizando flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução usando JavaScript. Comentei algumas linhas do CSS e alterei outras. Criei dois eventos `onload` e `onresize` que chamam uma função que posiciona o rodapé de acordo com a posição do topo, conteúdo e altura da janela.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   window.onload = ajusta_rodape;
   window.onresize = ajusta_rodape;

   function ajusta_rodape(){
      var c = document.querySelector("#conteudo").clientHeight; // altura do conteúdo
      var t15 = (window.innerHeight/100) * 15; // calcula os 15%
      var r = document.querySelector("#rodape"); // pega elemento do rodapé
      r.style.top = c+t15 +"px"; // ajusta a altura
   }
   
});
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
/* html,body {
   height: 100%;
} */
#topo {
   background: limegreen;
   /* position: static;
   left: 60px;
   top: 35px; */
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 200px;
}
#conteudo {
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   position: absolute;
   left: 15%;
   top: 15%;
   /* margin: 0 auto; */
   width: 70%;
   height: auto;
}
#rodape {
   /* bottom: 0; */
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 50px;
   /* position: relative; */
   position: absolute;
   background: limegreen;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="topo">
   <h1>Titulo</h1>
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum fim</p>
</div>
<div id="rodape">RODAPE</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma resposta usando `flex`.

Agora o topo sempre fica pregado no topo, o rodapé sempre fica pregado na base independente do tamanho do conteúdo.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
}

#topo {
    background: limegreen;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 200px;
}

#conteudo {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    position: relative;
    margin: 16px auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}

#rodape {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: limegreen;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
        -ms-grid-row-align: end;
        align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="topo">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div id="rodape">RODAPE</div>
```